# Jquery Ordering a sorted list, using function

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm using this plugin to change how my select list works. http://odyniec.net/projects/selectlist/

This seems pretty good and does what I want. It has the option to apply sorting using your own function.

> A custom sorting function can be used to arrange the selected items in
>   the desired order. The function takes two arguments which are two DOM
>   elements corresponding to the items being compared. The return value
>   should be true if the first item is considered to be greater than the
>   second one, or false otherwise.
>
> Here's an example of a sorting function that compares the two items by
>   their text converted to lowercase, resulting in case-insensitive
>   sorting (by default, sorting is case-sensitive):

```
$('select').selectList({
  sort: function (item1, item2) {
    return $(item1).text().toLowerCase() > $(item2).text().toLowerCase();
  }
});
```

My select list appears as :

```
value= 0    text= 0
value= 1    text= 1
value= 2    text= 2
value= 3    text= 3
value= 4    text= 4
value= 5    text= 5
value= at   text= @
value= dollar    text= $
value= school    text= School
value= location  text= Location
```

When the options are selected and shown by select list they don't appear in this order so I'd like to make use of the ability to use a custom function to sort as above.

Basically it should be any number in the correct order starting with 0, then @, $ and then School and Location at the bottom in that order.

Any ideas on how I can create a function to do this ?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example HTML?

Comment: You can create an object that maps the text to an order number, then compare those order numbers.

Comment: not sure how School comes before Location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea for a number and string sort is

```
sort: function (item1, item2) {
  const aText = $(item1).text().toLowerCase()
  const bText = $(item2).text().toLowerCase()
  const aNum = Number(aText)
  const bNum = Number(bText)
  if (!isNaN(nA) && isNaN(nB)){
    return -1
  } else if (isNaN(aNum) && !isNaN(bNum)){
    return 1
  } else if (!isNaN(aNum) && !isNaN(bNum)) {
    return  aNum > bNum ? 1 : -1
  }
  return aText.localeCompare(bText)
}
```

The thing with this is, location and school will be in alpha order, not reversed. If it has to be in that other order it will still need more logic.

Comment: Thanks this could help.. I'll have a play around with it.